# AVQueuePlayer playing items simultaneously rather than in sequence

Tags: objective-c, ios, avqueueplayer

I am trying to put together a simple app to play a pre-roll video followed by some content video.

Currently, I'm trying to use the AVQueuePlayer class to get this done.  Unfortunately, it seems to want to play the videos properly in sequence.

For example, the pre-roll plays by itself for a few seconds, then (prior to the pre-roll being complete) it starts to try and play the content video.  For a few seconds, the player seems to be at war with itself and switches back and forth between the two videos (neither playing very well at all).   Finally, when the pre-roll is finished, the content video then plays the rest of the way normally.

I've looked through the documentation for the AVQueuePlayer and I don't see anything obvious that I'm missing.

My code is pretty basic:

```
AVPlayerItem *preRollItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: preRollUrl];
AVPlayerItem *contentItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: contentUrl];

self.player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:preRollItem, contentItem, nil]];

[self.player play];
```

What is the trick to getting the videos to play in sequence.

Comment: Are you saying that AVQueuePlayer plays both sequentially queued videos at the very same time, visible for the user?

Comment: Essentially yes.   The player appears to be playing the last few seconds of the first video and the first few seconds of the second video at the same time.   Needless to say, this doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are actually testing on the device. From my experience the iOS5 simulator has big problems with `AVQueuePlayer` and does bizarre things.

I found the iOS4.3 simulator is doing a much better job when it comes to testing AVFoundation.

Comment: I had thought about that but surprisingly, it seems to do the same thing on the phone.

Comment: Have you tried using different videos? Also, your code can not be complete - please enhance it towards a minimal, fully functioning version. If possible, add the URLs you are testing against.